# Python graphics.py. How to get the return of checkMouse()?

Tags: python, graphics, zelle-graphics

```
win=GraphWin("test",410,505)

while win.checkMouse==None:
    rectangle=Rectangle(Point(100,100),Point(300,300))
    rectangle.draw(win)
    rectangle.undraw()
coordinate=win.checkMouse()
```

The coordinate keeps printing None. How can I get the coordinates of the `win.checkMouse()` when the window has been pressed?

Comment: you forgot `()` in first `win.checkMouse()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
win=GraphWin("test",410,505)

coordinate = win.checkMouse()
while coordinate == None:
    rectangle=Rectangle(Point(100,100),Point(300,300))
    rectangle.draw(win)
    rectangle.undraw()
    coordinate = win.checkMouse()
print coordinate
```

Try this.

checkMouse() function returns last mouse click or None if mouse has not been clicked since last call. So it makes clicked value to None while exiting the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `()` in first `win.checkMouse()`

In your example you have to click twice because first click (and coordinates) is catched by first `win.checkMouse()` in `while` loop. Second click will be catched by `coordinate = win.checkMouse()`

```
from graphics import *
import time

win = GraphWin("test", 410, 505)

while not win.checkMouse():
    rectangle = Rectangle(Point(100, 100), Point(300, 300))
    rectangle.draw(win)
    rectangle.undraw()

# time for second click
time.sleep(2)

coordinate = win.checkMouse()
print("coordinate:", coordinate)

win.close()
```

---

**EDIT:** Example without `sleep()`

```
from graphics import *

win = GraphWin("test", 410, 505)

rectangle = Rectangle(Point(100, 100), Point(300, 300))
rectangle.draw(win)

while True:
    coordinate = win.checkMouse()
    if coordinate:
        print("coordinate:", coordinate)
        break

win.close()
```

---

**EDIT:** binding function to mouse buttons

```
from graphics import *

# --- functions ---

def on_click_left_button(event):
    x = event.x
    y = event.y
    rectangle = Rectangle(Point(x, y), Point(x+100, y+100))
    rectangle.draw(win)

def on_click_right_button(event):
    win.close()
    win.quit()

# --- main ---

win = GraphWin("test", 410, 505)

win.bind('<Button-1>', on_click_left_button)
win.bind('<Button-3>', on_click_right_button)

win.mainloop()
```